# Debugging Python pygame program

Tags: python, debugging, pygame

```
from livewires import games, color

#Creating and validating the pygame screen.
scrwidth = 640
scrheight = 480
fps = 50
myscr = games.Screen(scrwidth, scrheight)
#Loading an image into memory to create an image object
wall_image = games.load_image("wall.jpg", transparent = False)
myscr.set_background (wall_image)
#Printing Arbitary Score
texty = games.Text(value = "Score: 2048321",
                   size = 70,
                   color = color.black,
                   x = 400,
                   y = 30)
myscr.add(texty)
myscr.mainloop()
```

For some reason, I am unable to print the score string in the position that I've assigned it to.

When I did the same thing without assigning variables to the given objects, I was able to do this successfully, but now I'm not that I've assigned it to a variable.

Any input would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: As requested, the working code.

```
from livewires import games, color

games.init(screen_width = 640, screen_height = 480, fps = 50)

wall_image = games.load_image("wall.jpg", transparent = False)
games.screen.background = wall_image

score = games.Text(value = 1756521,
                   size = 60,
                   color = color.black,
                   x = 550,
                   y = 30)
games.screen.add(score)

games.screen.mainloop()
```

Here we are! Working code:

```
from livewires import games, color

#Creating and validating the pygame screen.
scrwidth = 640
scrheight = 480
fpsy = 50
games.init(screen_width = scrwidth, screen_height =scrheight, fps = fpsy)
myscr = games.screen
#Loading an image into memory to create an image object
wall_image = games.load_image("wall.jpg", transparent = False)
myscr.background = wall_image
#Printing Arbitary Score
texty = games.Text(value = "Score: 2048321",
                   size = 70,
                   color = color.black,
                   x = 400,
                   y = 30)
myscr.add(texty)
myscr.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you provide the version of the code that you talk about, where you "did the same thing without assigning variables to the given objects", and it worked?

Comment: can you post the initial code before assigning variables, which worked?

Comment: Sure, posted right under the code that doesn't. Check in a second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think i know whats happening, if i am not wrong you could be assuming that

games.init(screen_width = 640, screen_height = 480, 
           fps = 50)

is the same thing as

```
scrwidth = 640
scrheight = 480
fps = 50
games.init(scrwidth, scrheight)
```

But that may not the case, the arguments int Screen look for name=value pairs in no particular order, so just value pairs may not work. You could however do this

```
scrwidth = 640
scrheight = 480
fps = 50
games.init(screen_width=scrwidth, screen_height= scrheight, fps=fps)
myscr = games.screen
```

I am guessing since your size was not set properly and x,y in text are absolute variables, your text may be messed up

Comment: I get this now:


TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'screen_width'

Comment: My bad, it should be init not Screen, why did u remove the init? so replace myscr = games.Screen(scrwidth, scrheight) with games.init(screen_width=scrwidth, screen_height= scrheight, fps=fps) and then add myscr = games.screen

Comment: Got it, thanks. Did the same, and there were a few things I didn't learn how to input properly (like the background), but it's all good now. I've placed the working copy in the question if you want to see it thanks again.

Comment: You bet, i am glad it helped.